# How to read every row in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

How do I read each line to determine if the customer has fully paid or partially paid or never paid?

I would like the code to read every line of each customer's bill until I find the `TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT = TOTAL_DUE`.  If found, then mark it as paid, if not found, read the next line until I found the `TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT <> 0` and `TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT < TOTAL_DUE` then mark it as partially paid or if the `TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT > TOTAL_DUE`, then mark it as paid.

For customer `111`, the bill is fully paid `-13129.54` from reading the first line.  But for customer `222`, the bill has not paid until the 2nd month for the amount of `-18768.9`, and for cumster `333`, the bill is not paid until the 3rd month and only pay it partially.  For customer `444`, the bill has never paid.(negative # means paid, positive # means amount charged)

```
CUSTOMER_ID  BILL_DATE    TOTAL_DUE    TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT
111          3/19/2015    13129.54     -13129.54
111          4/20/2015           0      0

222          3/25/2015    26334.12      0
222          4/24/2015                 -27000.00

333          2/25/2015    12720.21      0
333          3/25/2015                 -1000.00
333          4/24/2015                 -1071.15

444          2/26/2015    12266.6       0            
444          3/26/2015                  0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'd likely have to SUM the total paid and group by some of the other fields.

Comment: Would a customer (say 111) have multiple Total_DUE lines. Like maybe for customer 111 they geta new Total_DUE line on 07/01/2015? Or is this a one stop shop. Comparing the SUM(Total_DUE) to the sum(Total_Payment_Amt)?

Comment: Is this a sample of your raw data?

Comment: Yes  it is a sample of raw data.  It only has one total_due after join (my original code has tables join and I use rank() over in order to get the data I show above), but I got to the point I don't know a better way to read the lines when some customers do not pay at the first month like customer '111'.

Comment: How do I read each line and sum them up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a task for a Windowed Aggregate Function, a running total?

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, BILL_DATE, TOTAL_DUE, TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT,
   SUM(TOTAL_DUE) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID 
         ORDER BY BILL_DATE 
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS due,
   SUM(TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT)
   OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID 
         ORDER BY BILL_DATE 
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS pay,
   CASE 
     WHEN due + pay <= 0 THEN 'paid'
     WHEN pay = 0 THEN 'not paid'
     ELSE 'partially paid'
   END 
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 1):

This will sum the `TOTAL_DUE` and `TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT` for each `CUSTOMER_ID`.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, 
       MIN(BILL_DATE) AS [FIRST_BILL], 
       MAX(BILL_DATE) AS [LAST_BILL], 
       SUM(TOTAL_DUE), 
       SUM(TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

Change `TABLE_NAME` for the actual name of the table. You'll be able to determine if the customer paid the total amount by comparing the last two columns.

To sum the last two columns on the table you could do:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, 
       MIN(BILL_DATE) AS [FIRST_BILL], 
       MAX(BILL_DATE) AS [LAST_BILL], 
       SUM(TOTAL_DUE + TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT) AS [AMOUNT_DUE]
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
```

Then you would get the amount yet to be paid in a single row.

If you just wish to sum a single line, forget the `group by` and simply do:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, 
       BILL_DATE, 
       (TOTAL_DUE + TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT) AS [AMOUNT_DUE]
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Is there a way to read one line and sum it up and then read the next line and sum it up like the 2nd paragraph I posted above in question? Because there are cases customer pay at the first month, and other customers pay at the 2nd or 3rd month.

Comment: I included a way to do that above. Does that your question?

Comment: @bmpasini I think both @angelcake and my answers answer that. It's the `GROUP BY` that groups the customers together.

Comment: @bmpasini but if you mean for just one customer at a time. you want `WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?" to get a single customer balance.

Comment: I used `group by` in my first answer. Then @angelcake said she wanted to sum each line, that's why the second option below.

Comment: Yeah sorry I posted my comment before yours came through. Doesn't my answer do the same? SUM(INV_AMT) assuming no TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT. Given it's bad practice to put totals in tables when debits and credits are available to work it out.

Comment: I have tried SUM but I have different scenarios in the real data that's why I need to read each line to sum up.

Comment: I think I know your issue. I should add it to my answer.. You have "13129.54" adding to other decimals. Make all your fields integers. If your storing by 2 decimal points. Then multiply by 10 before you store them.

Comment: I'll elaborate a bit more. Arithmetic in SQL is odd if you don't know what your doing. So the best option is to store all your numbers as integers. Whole numbers. Then divide by 100 to get back to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

I would not store `TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMT` as a field. At least not in the same table.
I think you need to do some research on "double entry book keeping" might also help.

Produce a statement type system.

```
CUSTOMER_ID    BILL_DATE    INV_AMT
111            3/19/2015    13129.54

select CUSTOMER_ID, BILL_DATE, SUM(INV_AMT) AS invamt
from TABLE_NAME
group by CUSTOMER_ID
```

If the "statement" is until a certain period, say 1st of the month. Then add `WHERE BILL_DATE < 07-01-2015`

Or whatever date you wish.

**EDIT**

Figured after commenting with @bmpasini I should make some corrections.

- `invamt` will give you the total due by the given `CUSTOMER_ID`
- If wanting just the balance of one customer then you want `WHERE CUSTOMER_ID < 07-01-2015 AND CUSTOMER_ID = ?`

**EDIT 2**

Afer commenting with @angelcake. Arithmetic in SQL is odd if you don't know what your doing.

So the best option is to store all your numbers as integers. Whole numbers. Then divide by 100 to get back to 2 decimal places.

`int INV_AMT = 13129.54 * 100;`

`echo INV_AMT (1312954 / 100);`

If that doesn't makes sense comment and I'll add more examples.

Comment: I should add my dates are different because we do dd/mm/yyyy. Sometimes forget to put the month first.